# Integrate square function

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy, numerical-integration

> **I need to make the fourier series of an square function.**

To get this a have a function y = square(t)

i need to make the integral of (2/p)*(square(t)*cos((2pi/p)*t)) from 0 to a variable I type for example p = 10 but i cant make this integral because every time i try to do this with scipy i get an error with the square function.

```
from scipy.signal import *
from scipy.integrate import quad
from numpy import *
p = 10
na = arange(0,10,1)
def integrand(t, a, b):
    return square(t)*cos(b*((2*pi)/a)*t)
i,err = quad(integrand,0,p, args=(p,na))
y = i
```

> quadpack.error: Supplied function does not return a valid float.

Comment: would be nice if you showed what the error was.

Comment: I don't get an error with square running this code. However, I get a type error multiplying tuple i with 2/p.

Comment: So you do get an error...

Comment: I edit it and add the error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`quad`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.quad.html) returns 2 parameters, the integral and the absolute value of the error, you just have to unpack it.

```
from scipy.signal import *
from scipy.integrate import quad
from numpy import *
p = 10
def integrand(t, a):
    return square(t)*cos(((2*pi)/a)*t)
i, err = quad(integrand,0,p, args=(p,))
y = (2/p)*i
```

---

**update:**

```
from scipy.signal import *
from scipy.integrate import quad
from numpy import *
p = 10
na = arange(0,10,1)
y = []

def integrand(t, a, b):
    return square(t)*cos(b*((2*pi)/a)*t)

for e in na:
    i,err = quad(integrand,0,p, args=(p, e))
    y.append(i)

print(y)
```

Comment: if i need to use a vector inside the function  like in my question i get an error

Comment: @DanielDaza 
You can not change the error every time, you should also read the documentation. you must iterate. I will update my answer.